# jquery one row sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite, sprite-sheet

I'm working on animating the movement of a sprite (rotate on the spot - left to right and rotate 90 degrees from a standing position to face upwards or downwards) using a single-row sprite sheet containing 30 separate images, but I don't know where to start. I've had a look on the interwebs and there are suggestions of using a third-party sprite library such as spritely to handle this. I want to achieve this using just jquery (1.7 in my case) and javascript. Are there any simple examples on how I can achieve this?

Comment: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for some sort of tutorial, i searched 'sprite-sheet js' and found this on my 2nd or 3rd hit:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/